# How to merge missing records from the backup table to the original one

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have 2 schema of database (on oracle 11.g) : BackUp and Original.

The table TAX has the same structure on both schema.

It hasn't a primary key but has as index :
 TAXCOD, COUNTRY, LONG_SHORT and FUND.

I want to select the records that are missing from the original table and found on the backup.

I checked the Left Outer Join query on this Link

http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

And, I wrote this query according to what is mentioned :

```html
select * 
from BackUp.TAX x 
left outer join Original.TAX y 
  on (x.TAXCOD = y.TAXCOD and
      x.COUNTRY = y.COUNTRY and
      x.LONG_SHORT = y.LONG_SHORT and
      x.FUND = y.FUND) 
where  y.TAXCOD is NULL
   and y.COUNTRY is NULL
   and y.LONG_SHORT is NULL
   and y.FUND is NULL
```

but this query brings even commun records between the 2 tables and not just missing one .
Please could you explain for me where the problem lies.
Thanks for advance.

Comment: How can you identify a common record without a primary key?

Comment: A unique record has unique combination in the columns TAXCOD, COUNTRY, LONG SHORT, and Fund

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `EXCEPT` to find rows in one table that does not exist in the other table:

```
select * from BackUp.TAX
except all
select * from Original.TAX
```

Or, if you just want to match the mentioned columns, use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select * from BackUp.TAX x
where NOT EXISTS (select 1 from Original.TAX y
                  where x.TAXCOD = y.TAXCOD
                    and x.COUNTRY = y.COUNTRY
                    and x.LONG_SHORT = y.LONG_SHORT
                    and x.FUND = y.FUND)
```

Comment: Great to hear! Which one did you chose?

Comment: The problem is that I want the solution done with Left  Outer Join .Sorry for being so demanding

Comment: Why that specific LEFT OUTER JOIN requirement?

Comment: The First One Worked but Instead of except all we should work with minus since I work with Oracle : Concerning Left Outer Join I'am trying to maintain some source code so I'am stuck to currently existing code

Comment: is there any propositions ?